# Finder or Photos?

Tags: photos.app

Does storing photos in the Photos app or finder take up more space? Or are they the same? 
I'm trying to free up some storage, and I have a lot of photos, so just wondering whether moving all that into the Photos app will change anything. 
(By the way, I DON'T use iCloud so don't tell me to store it there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing your photos into **Photos** will take *a little more* space, simply due to the fact that **Photos** will generate thumbnails for your full-size photos, and store additional metadata, such as facial recognition data, etc.

**Photos** also allows you to make and save edits to your photos, which will take up additional storage on top of the space your photos occupy on their own.

The extra metadata occupies a negligible amount of additional storage, although edits might, depending on how many photos you’ve edited.

So yes, storing straight files on your hard drive will save you some space, but it’s also a totally barebones storage/browsing solution. How much space you save will depend on your use of the **Photos** app.

On the other hand, if you use **Photos** in such a way that storing your pictures there causes a vast difference in storage needs, then allegedly you’re also making good use of that extra storage.